# Curl output file not created

Tags: file, curl, output, httpwebresponse

**Overview**: We use an off the shelf mapping tool to do our data mapping (creation of JSON files, etc).  We then use that tool to call an exe in order to have Curl post the JSON file to the API.  This is working great, with the exception of being able to get the output file created (to show us the results of the API connection).  When we run the exe from the command line the output file gets created successfully, but when we run the exact same command by calling it from our other tool, the output file doesn’t get created.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

We’ve the following curl command to process the PUT API call. We use a request file and we intend to produce a response output file (to monitor the webAPI result) and a trace log (for debugging purposes).

```
curl --request PUT "https://client.mirakl.net//api/orders/order101/tracking" ^
-d @"D:\HSG\Test\PUTOR23\order101.json" ^
-o "D:\HSG\Test\PUTOR23\Output\order101_out.txt" ^
--trace-ascii "D:\HSG\Test\PUTOR23\Outputorder101_TRACE.txt"
```

This command works fine from command line (both output and trace files are produced).

But when we execute the exact same command from our mapping tool it is not producing the output file (the Trace file does get updated successfully).  Curl is able to read the request data file and it also produces the trace file. But for some reason the output file is NOT generated.

We’ve tried -o, -O and console redirect > options but none seems to produce the output file when called from our mapping tool.

Comment: Try changing your tool to invoke some simple command to create the output file (in Unix this would be `touch` but you are using Windows, so try `copy nul: "D:\HSG\Test\PUTOR23\Output\order101_out.txt"`), and see if it works. If it does, focus on `curl`. If it doesn't, focus on the environment your tool is running. Maybe there is something funky about it.

Comment: What happens if you try to put the output file in the trace directory? Maybe the "Output" directory has some weird permissions the tool can't access? Where does stderr go, can you see it? Or what happens if you swap the trace filename and the output filename (including paths), since the trace file works?

Comment: Thank you @eewanco. We've verified that there's no file read/write access issue (we're able to read data file with -d @<file> and output --trace<file>). The issues is specific to output. Also I doubt if its curl related because I tried a simple .bat with > operator to output data to a physical (type sample.json > output.json) but again it failed from our tool. Yet I find it strange why curl is able to produce the trace but not the output (will try silent mode). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing to be rectified in curl command options, we suspect that our mapping tool was somehow preventing the console output all together (thus the output file might also have not been created because no output was allowed).

> To overcome the limitation, we resorted to **wrap the curl command
>   within a batch (.bat) file**. And made sure that neither curl nor the
>   batch file produce any output on console. Using curl's --silent option
>   and quietly redirecting the output to a file using -o (which we
>   wanted). And it worked!

Somehow, the curl command execution within the batch file wasn't disturbed by our mapping tool and it allowed creation of the response output file. Patchy as it sounds, but it worked.